# Saving already created PDF or CSV file by Angular (not exporting)

Tags: java, angular, file, io

I have two endpoints

```
POST `reports/pdf`
{
payload
}
```

And:

```
POST `reports/csv`
{
payload
}
```

which return temporary files as 
`file:///C:/Users/UserFolder/AppData/Local/Temp/csv6677594787854925068.csv` and `file:///C:/Users/UserFolder/AppData/Local/Temp/pdf6677594753424925068.pdf`

I created services with methods like this one to get that file:

```
exportReport(summaryCustomerReport: SummaryCustomerReport): Observable<Object> {
const exportUrl = `${this.reportsUrl}/pdf`;


return this.http.post(exportUrl, summaryCustomerReport);
}
private get reportsUrl() {
return `${environment.backendUrl}/reports`;
}
```

And then I tried to use that service:

```
downloadPdf() {
this.hoursWorkedForCustomersService.exportReport(this.summaryCustomerReport, ExportFileFormat[ExportFileFormat.PDF]).subscribe(
  result => {
    saveAs(result, 'new.pdf');
   },
  error => { console.error(error) },
  () => {}
);}
```

But I have an error called

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/UserFolder/AppData/Local/Temp/csv6677594787854925068.csv' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

And also:

`ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/UserFolder/AppData/Local/Temp/csv6677594787854925068.csv'.`

I tried to use solution from similar questions like running chrome with CMD like `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security`, it doesn't helped.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things

1. put your file into your app root directory, then you can access it by http:://localhost:4200/csv6677594787854925068.csv instead file:///C:/Users/UserFolder/AppData/Local/Temp/csv6677594787854925068.csv

or

2. set a new filed in response header as "Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *".

Comment: 2. You mean on backend or frontend?